# Error while opening trace file in Traceview in Android

Tags: android, android-traceview

I am using ADT 20.0.3. I am opening my trace file using following command:

> C:>traceview "C:/Users/androdev/mytracefile.trace"

But I am getting following error:

```
Failed to read the trace filejava.io.IOException: Key section does not have an *end marker
at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.parseKeys(DmTraceReader.java:420)
at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.generateTrees(DmTraceReader.java:91)
at com.android.traceview.DmTraceReader.<init>(DmTraceReader.java:87)
at com.android.traceview.MainWindow.main(MainWindow.java:286)
```

mytracefile.trace is generated by using `Debug.startMethodTracing("mytracefile")` and `Debug.stopMethodTracing()` methods in my code.

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That simply means the tracefile is empty. Most probably Debug.stopMethodTracing() is not being called, and thus the tracefile data ends up being empty.

Comment: Yes, in my case the tracefile took a while to be created, and I had to wait another 20 seconds for that to finish.